# Beautiful url with htaccess not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking at a lot of htaccess code to fix this, but i am lost, I tried to change it arround 50 times but still with no result, if you can help me, it would be appreciated :

I am trying to create something like this :
www.domain.com/expositions/nameoftheexposition/

For now, I can easily do www.domain.com/expositions/ without any problem, but i can't seem to be able to access the next level.

here's my htaccess :

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

    RewriteRule ^expositions/([^/\.]+)$ expositions?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^expositions/([^/.]+)/?$ expositions?name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Note that this rewrites an _incoming_ URI from SEO-format ("pretty") to dynamic (?name=xxxxx). It is _your_ responsibility to create the link on your page in the SEO-format in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but now i'm now with the problem that my css, images and other stuff are not global, could you help or refer me for that? thx again

Comment: For that use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`